# Quick Match waiting room pops one time and leave with Google play games in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, real-time, google-play-games, multiplayer

I have a weird behavior with the Google Play Games plugin in unity.

After i add my code to send and receive realtime messages, the UI for waiting room before a game, pops one time, leave, and nothing happens (normally i would match the other player, the game is running on a second device).

Before i add my code, everything worked fine (the screen stays until an opponent is find, and the game started).

I don't know why this issue appears.

Here is the log when i click to get a Quick Match (random match):

```
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.c__AnonStorey15:<>m__D() (at E:\A
pplication\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\Logger.cs:59)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() (at E
:\Application\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:
135)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): (Filename: E Line: 0)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 08/01/17 13:19:21 +02:00 DEBUG: Not
leaving room since showing UI
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Obj
ect)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String
, Object[])
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.c__AnonStorey15:<>m__D() (at E:\A
pplication\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\Logger.cs:59)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() (at E
:\Application\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:
135)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): (Filename: E Line: 0)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 08/01/17 13:19:21 +02:00 DEBUG: Ente
ring internal callback for RealtimeManager#InternalWaitingRoomUICallback
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Obj
ect)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String
, Object[])
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.c__AnonStorey15:<>m__D() (at E:\A
pplication\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\Logger.cs:59)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() (at E
:\Application\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:
135)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): (Filename: E Line: 0)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 08/01/17 13:19:21 +02:00 DEBUG: Show
WaitingRoomUI Response: VALID
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Obj
ect)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String
, Object[])
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.c__AnonStorey15:<>m__D() (at E:\A
pplication\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\Logger.cs:59)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() (at E
:\Application\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:
135)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): (Filename: E Line: 0)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): [Play Games Plugin DLL] 08/01/17 13:19:21 +02:00 DEBUG: Conn
ecting state ShowWaitingRoomUI: room pcount:1 status: AUTO_MATCHING
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Obj
ect)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String
, Object[])
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.c__AnonStorey15:<>m__D() (at E:\A
pplication\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\Logger.cs:59)
I/Unity ( 6389): GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update() (at E
:\Application\R Hockey\Assets\GooglePlayGames\OurUtils\PlayGamesHelperObject.cs:
135)
I/Unity ( 6389):
I/Unity ( 6389): (Filename: E Line: 0)
I/Unity ( 6389):
D/dalvikvm( 3322): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3216K, 31% free 17725K/25376K, paused 6ms
+7ms, total 95ms
W/ActivityManager( 2461): `mDVFSHelper.release()
```

I found that the problem appears when i'm using this line to send message to the other player:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessageToAll (false, bytedata);
```

Why is this line causing the pop of the UI?

(when i didn't had this line, everything go back to normal. But this line is the only whay to send messages, according to the [github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/RTMP.md)).

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your code looks like, you may want to check the following:

- [Configuration and initialization of Play Game Services](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).
- steps on how you should [launch the waiting room UI](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui)
- Note that you should only call `PlayGamesPlatform.Activate` once in your application. Making this call will not display anything on the screen and will not interact with the user in any way.

Lastly, workaround used in addressing an error in [this post](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/35063380-createquickgame-pops-default-room-ui-once) might also help. Don't call `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.ShowWaitingRoomUI();`
in `OnRoomSetupProgress(float percent)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's weird to not call `ShowWaitingRoomUI()` in `OnRoomSetupProgress(float percent)`, because in the github, they are coding like this. But how could i get the `Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent` in Unity and c#?